# I want the User to be able to continue using the program. But Im still Sketchy using while loop

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
print'Free fall distance and velocity calculator'  
g=9.81
def finalvelocity(t):
    vf=g*t
    return vf
def height(t):
    h=0.5*g*t
    return h
t=input('Enter the value of time in seconds: ')
print'What do you want to get?'
print'[1]. Final Velocity'
print'[2]. Height'

choice= input('Enter Selected Number: ')

if choice==1:
    print 'Answer is', finalvelocity(t),'meter per second'

if choice==2:
    print 'Answer is', height(t), 'meters'

if choice>2:
    print 'Invalid Selection'
if choice<1:
    print 'Invalid Selection'
for choice in range(choice>2):
    n=raw_input('Do you want to continue?[y]yes/[n]no: ')


    while True:

            t=input('Enter the value of time in seconds: ')
            print'What do you want to get?'
            print'[1]. Final Velocity'
            print'[2]. Height'

            choice= input('Enter Selected Number: ')

            if choice==1:
                print 'Answer is', finalvelocity(t),'meter per second'

            if choice==2:
                print 'Answer is', height(t), 'meters'

            if choice>2:
                print 'Invalid Selection'
            if choice<1:
                print 'Invalid Selection'


    if n==n:
        break
```

Comment: What's the actual question here? What does the program do and what do you think it should or shouldn't do?

Comment: I want the user to be able to continue using the program unless he wanted to exit. But im still unfamiliar using the while loop. Someone had suggested  me to use while loop if i wanted an infinite loop however, I dont know how to integrate it to my program.

Comment: The program works up to the line which has the decision statement, but this program only works one way and the user needs to run the program again if he wanted to try another input. I want the user to be able to continue using the program without running it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question. You can use infinite loops to run the program again and again until the user wishes to exit. A super simple example of this would be:

```
while True:
    t = raw_input("Do you want to exit? y/n: ")
    if t == 'y':
        break
    else:
        print "You stayed!"
```

As for your code, here's how you'd make it run infinite times. Note how if the user selects 'No' the code `break`s out of the loop to exit the program.

```
print 'Free fall distance and velocity calculator'
g = 9.81


def finalvelocity(t):
    vf = g*t
    return vf


def height(t):
    h = 0.5*g*t
    return h

# Start an infinite loop of user input until they exit
while True:
    # Ask for time
    t = input('Enter the value of time in seconds: ')

    # Ask for query type
    print'What do you want to get?'
    print'[1]. Final Velocity'
    print'[2]. Height'
    choice= input('Enter Selected Number: ')

    # Perform calculations
    if choice==1:
        print 'Answer is', finalvelocity(t), 'meter per second'
    if choice==2:
        print 'Answer is', height(t), 'meters'
    else:
        print 'Invalid Selection'

    # Offer the user a chance to exit
    n = raw_input('Do you want to calculate another? [y]yes/[n]no: ')
    if n == 'n':
        # User wants to exit
        break # Break out of the infinite loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the modifications, I'll try this program and maybe add some more functions. This is a very great help thanks!

Comment: No worries. If you're happy with the answer please remember to accept it